# BarcodeScanner input in a Textfield (Keystroke)

Tags: java

i have an Idea for a litte Project i want to compare some Numbers with a simple logic, and for that i have generated many Barcodes and want to scan them and i think i could handle it with the KeyStroke. Is it possible even if the active window is NOT the Gui where the Textfield is that he detect my Prefix and then write the string in the Textfield and end with the Suffix?

Prefix is: TAB+*+PageDown

Suffix is: Carriage Return (HERE he should leave Textfield) or can i create a new Keystroke Event here and a .getActionMap... and than do..

My idea is use .getActionMap()

```
...
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

JTextField text = new JTextField();

panel.getActionMap().put("foo", new AbstractAction() { public void actionPerformed
(ActionEvent e) { 
text.setText(br.readLine());
}
```

and a InputMap

```
InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap();   inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 
InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | InputEvent.VK_TAB), "foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a class controller wich manages all the différent gui classes.so you Can Use all variables from the same class and dispatcher it where you need